# alert function in JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, forms, asp-classic, alert

I have an old page created in clasic asp, contain a form, I am trying to submit the form using JavaScript function after checking the values available in the form.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="vendorCheckDates.asp" name="Searchform" id="submit_Form">
    Select Type of Search: </b>
    <select size="1" name="Query" class="button">
        <option selected name="vNAME" value="vNAME"> Name</option>
        <option name="vNUM" value="vNUM"> Number</option>
        <option name="vEM" value="vEM">Email </option>
        <option name="vFAX" value="vFAX">Fax </option>
    </select>
    <b>:</b>
    <input type="text" name="hsearch" id="hsearch">
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend><strong>Type</strong></legend>
        <input type="radio" value="gov" name="tType" >Gov
        <input type="radio" value="gfos" name="tType">GFOS
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button" value="Search" name="hfind" Onclick="SubmitForm()">
</form>
```

The function

```
function SubmitForm() {
    var hsearch = document.all.submit_Form.hsearch.value;            
    var tType = document.getElementById('tType').value;            
    if ((hsearch = ! '') && (hsearch = ! null)) {               
        if ((tType = ! '') && (tType = ! null)) {
            document.all.submit_Form.submit();
        } else { alert("please select search type");}
    } else { alert("please write search criteria"); }
}
```

When I run the form the field hsearch is empty, but when I click submit the value will be true, its strange since I still didnt write anything in the input field hsearch, thats why the sels part in JavaScript function will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write `hsearch != ''` instead of `hsearch = ! ''`.

What you are doing is not checking for a value, but assigning a value that returns true.

```
hsearch = ! ''
=> hsearch = !''
=> hsearch = true
=> true
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using wrong operator. it should be

```
 if ((hsearch != '') && (hsearch != null)) {               
        if ((tType != '') && (tType != null)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var hsearch = document.all.submit_Form.hsearch.value;
```

Try:

```
var hsearch = document.getElementById('hsearch').value;
```

You can always debug the value by putting an `alert` like:

```
alert(hsearch)
```